# UIPopoverController slow animation when changing content size

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController in which I push on a UiNavigationController and then subsequent view controllers as needed.  This works great if the preferred content size of all the views are the same but when the UIPopOver needs to expand to support a larger preferred content size the animation is excruciatingly slow.  I've tested this on the simulator and multiple iPad generations all with the same results, a 2-3 second animation while the UIPopover expands the view to support the larger view controller.

How can I speed up this animation?

```
    OTBAddNewClassViewController *addVC = [[OTBAddNewClassViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"addNewClass" bundle:nil];
    [addVC setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 220)];
    [addVC setDelegate:self];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:addVC];
    self.popVC = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navController];
    [self.popVC setDelegate:self];

    NSInteger popWidth = addVC.view.frame.size.width;
    [self.popVC presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, popWidth, addVC.view.frame.size.height) inView:self.tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you using Nibs, Storyboard, or doing it programatically?

Comment: Couple of points -- UIPopoverController is not typically pushed onto the navigation stack, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you are pushing it onto a nav controller. Also, without posting the code of what you are trying to do there's not much help we can give.

Comment: Are you sure that you did't have any performance problems? And did't lock main thread?

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to set the `delegate` of your `UINavigationController`, then override `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and do something like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGSize contentSize = viewController.preferredContentSize;
    [self.popVC setPopoverContentSize:contentSize animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer.  It is much simpler than the one I provided, avoids the use of deprecated properties, and uses the viewController's preferredContentSize instead of CGSizeMake.  +1

Comment: See my comment to Aron's answer, not about the popover not expanding to meet the new view controller's size, instead how slow that animation is.

Comment: I find it strange that your animation is still slow. Are you using Mavericks? If so, if you are running this in the iOS 6 simulator, it will be slow. That is a known issue. Also, you're sure you haven't "toggled slow animations" in the simulator?

Comment: It's slow in the simulator and on an iPad 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

To change the speed at which the UIPopoverController animates it's contentSize, try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0  // Set your desired duration here
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];
```

**Original Answer:**

If I am following you correctly, you have a UIPopoverController that contains a UINavigationController that will be able to push/pop additional viewControllers inside of the popoverController, and you would like the popOverController to re-size dynamically based on the size of the view in the pushed/poppoed viewController.

I've implemented similar functionality into an iPad application, and I did it using the following:

In the viewController that is contained in the popoverController, I use the contentSizeForPopover property to re-size the popover in viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 280); // Set your size here.
}
```

However, it is worth noting that the contentSizeForViewInPopover is deprecated in iOS 7, and you will eventually have to update the code to have the popoverController update the height using setPopoverContentSize:

```
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 280)];
```

In my application, I had to do this by setting up a protocol to pass the intended height back to my UIPopoverController.  I did this with the following code:

The Protocol:

```
@protocol MyProtocolName <NSObject>

- (void)setPopOverContentSize:(CGSize)size;
```

The delegate property on my viewControllers:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyProtocolName> delegate;
```

The implementation in the viewControllers:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    ....

    [self.delegate setPopOverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 280)];
}
```

The class the contains the popoverController that conforms to the protocol I've created:

```
- (void)setPopOverContentSize:(CGSize)size {
    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController *)self.appPopOver.contentViewController;

    UIViewController* currentViewController = navController.topViewController;
    [myPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:size];
}
```

You'll need to customize the snippets I've posted for your specific classes, but I've tried to provide the same process that I followed to achieve the effect you desire.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The popover does dynamically grow to match the size of the newly pushed view controller, thats not the issue. The problem is how long it takes for that animation to take place, it's about 2 seconds which makes for a really disjointed experience.

Comment: Wrapping it in the animation block has no impact on the performance.

Comment: Where are you calling the code posted above?  I just noticed you said it was taking 2-3 seconds to change size, so it makes that the animation block didn't work, because there is probably something else going on.  Can you post some more code showing us how you are calling the code above?